# From and To date search in database PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Good day! I am trying to create a "search by date" option in my website that will retrieve the records in the database whose dates matched the users' input. I have these select boxes:

```
<!-- FROM -->
<select name="from_month" id="from_month">
 <option selected>-- MONTH --</option>
 <option value="january">January</option>
 ...
 <option value="december">December</option>
</select>

<select name="from_day" id="from_day">
 <option selected>-- DAY --</option>
 <?php $i = 1;
  while ($i <= 31) {
  echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
  $i++;
  }
 ?>
</select>

<select name="from_year" id="from_year">
 <option selected>-- YEAR --</option>
 <?php $i = date('Y');
  while ($i <= 2040) {
  echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
  $i++;
  }
 ?>
</select>
<!-- FROM (END) -->

<!-- TO -->
<select name="to_month" id="to_month">
 <option selected>-- MONTH --</option>
 <option value="1">January</option>
 ...
 <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select name="to_day" id="to_day">
 <option selected>-- DAY --</option>
 <?php $i = 1;
  while ($i <= 31) {
  echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
  $i++;
  }
 ?>
</select>

<select name="to_year" id="to_year">
 <option selected>-- YEAR --</option>
 <?php $i = date('Y');
  while ($i <= 2040) {
  echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
  $i++;
  }
 ?>
</select>
<!-- TO (END) -->
```

What I originally plan to do is get all the "from_" values and store it into a variable '$from'. The same goes for the "to_". Because my database for dates looks like this:

```
id | title(text) | date_submitted(date) |
 1 | Lorem Ipsum |     2015-01-20       |
```

Any help would be appreciated on how I would accomplish this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can just use MySQL's *BETWEEN*: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: Hi, Dimas. Thank you for your comment. I am trying it right now but I don't know how to parse the variables from "from_" and "to_" to date format so I could compare it into my database records.

Comment: Use `value=01`, `value=02` etc instead of "january", "february" in the options of the `from_month` select box  for convenience. `to_month` select box is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know every part of the date, MySQL's `BETWEEN` would do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE mydate BETWEEN 'from_date' AND 'to_date'
```

*from_date* and *to_date* are your variables, get through the form.

As @AnoopS stated, use numbers to value your month boxes.

And remember to prevent injections using *mysqli* or *PDO* with prepared statements.